# Javascript code doesn’t work when the first piece of code inserts before the second piece

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript code doesn’t work when the first piece of code

```
var parag = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i = 0; i <= parag.length; i++) {
parag[i].innerHTML = parag[i].innerHTML + parag[i].tagName.toLowerCase();
}
```

inserts before the second piece.

```
var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
var li = document.getElementById("li");
var newli = document.createElement("li");
newli.innerHTML = "newli";
ul.insertBefore(newli, li);
```

And after the first piece of code all code doesn’t works, but works if I insert it before the problematic code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p>10</p>
  <p>10</p>
  <ul id = "ul">
    <li id = "li">li</li>
  </ul>
  <script>
  var parag = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  for (var i = 0; i <= parag.length; i++) {
    parag[i].innerHTML = parag[i].innerHTML + parag[i].tagName.toLowerCase();
  }

  var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
  var li = document.getElementById("li");
  var newli = document.createElement("li");
  newli.innerHTML = "newli";
  ul.insertBefore(newli, li);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any errors in console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi because of you are using `<=` for your array length and you walk out of your array, hence you should use `<` in for loop,

```
for (var i = 0; i <= parag.length; i++) {//wrong usage

for (var i = 0; i < parag.length; i++) {//correct usage
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `i < parag.length` instead of `i <= parag.length`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p>10</p>
  <p>10</p>
  <ul id = "ul">
    <li id = "li">li</li>
  </ul>
  <script>
  var parag = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  for (var i = 0; i < parag.length; i++) {
    parag[i].innerHTML = parag[i].innerHTML + parag[i].tagName.toLowerCase();
  }

  var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
  var li = document.getElementById("li");
  var newli = document.createElement("li");
  newli.innerHTML = "newli";
  ul.insertBefore(newli, li);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```